# WWW::Mechanize find link and follow link

Tags: www-mechanize

Using WWW::Mechanize, I've try to find link with `text_regex => qr/Next/` and follow the link with success, but I'm having problem with the link that look like this:

```
"< img alt="" src="images/pager-spacer.gif" >
    < input type="submit" class="link-btn" id="ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_phSearchHeader_pgrTop_btnNext" onclick="javascript:suppressPopUp();" value="Next" name="ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$phSearchHeader$pgrTop$btnNext> < img alt="" src="images/gtn.gif"> "
```

How do I find and follow link like that.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to just submit the form since the input type is submit, `$mech->submit();` should work

Comment: if there's many forms in the page just specify which form, by $mech->form_number(1); or form_name("")...